# Where to put ServiceWorker snippet - head or body?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, offline-mode

I'm starting with service-workers (a bit late to the party, but better then never), and I place my `<script>if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {..}</script>` snippet at the very bottom, bellow my other snippet (`System.import(...)`).

Is that a good place for it? Where else should I put the standard script snippet on a page: head or maybe start of body? Or put it externally in another script?

More important - why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how heavyweight your service worker is, and how much JavaScript needs to execute on your page during the initial visit, it may or may not make a difference. But you can read [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/registration) on service worker registration best practices for more insight as to when it might matter.

The takeaway from the article is that a reasonable pattern is to use

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
  });
}
```

to register your service worker. That could appear pretty much anywhere on your page, as long as it runs before the `load` event is fired.

Comment: Hoped to get more detailed answer, but I guess this at least partially answers what I wanted to know. Sorry for the late acknowledgement, I was busy for a while and now returning to this question.

Comment: Is there anything that's not clear, after reading the longer explanation in that article? It shouldn't really matter where that code snippet is placed, since the actual registration won't happen until after the `load` event has fired.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't read the article, just your answer. I'll look through the article in more details when I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I think doing the registration in the head is better just in case you have some third-party requests going on in the head and you need to configure some runtime caching...

```
...
    <link href='/favicon.png' rel='icon' type='image/png'>
    <link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest">

    <script>
        'serviceWorker' in navigator && window.addEventListener('load', navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js'))
    </script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bundle.css">
</head>
...
```